# Add endpoints to top level schema in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a `django-tastypie` project, where I've added nested resources to the schema.  I'd like to add these endpoints to the top level schema, generated in `api.top_level`, but I don't see an easy way of doing this without re-writing the `top_level` method and hard coding the new endpoints.

Is there an easy way of adding nested resources to the top level schema, or is there a better way of doing this.

E.g. adding `list-endpoint` and `schema` fields for each nested endpoint in the parent schema.